# Регулярное выражение для даты

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть маска регулярного выражения для определения даты

```
((0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){1,2}[\.\\/-](0?[1-9]|1[012]){1,2}[\.\\/-](((19|20)\d\d)|(\d\d)))
```

Есть выражение:

```
д.15-12/12 - 14.12.12
```

15-12/12 - номер документа, 14.12.12 - дата документа

Если использовать вышеуказанную маску, то в результат попадет и номер и дата, а мне нужна только дата.

Вопрос: как написать маску так, что бы, например нашли разделитель точку, что бы следующим разделителем была тоже точка.

Спасибо.

Comment: выделяете вашу точку в группу, круглыми скобками, например `([.,])` а потом ссылаетесь далее на нее по номеру группы, например `\1`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/AypMfP/1

Comment: Mike, спасибо. Я читал про это, но никак не мог правильно составить выражение. Выручил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) и [Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman)

Итоговая маска будет такой:

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\.\\\/-])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(((19|20)\d\d)|(\d\d))
```

Comment: Вы ее проверьте на такой дате `1111.1111.1999` и удивитесь :Р

Comment: Visman, а почему так? Где моя ошибка? Никак не пойму.

Comment: `{1,2}` зачем используете, если в группе у вас все прописано? В первой группе от 1 или 01 до 31, во второй группе от 1 или 01 до 12.

Comment: наверное потому что я не до конца понимаю правила регулярных выражений. Думал, что {1,2} это я ограничу кол-во совпадений, как раз от 1111, а оказалось, что наоборот сделал. Спасибо.