# Валидация поля DATE в модели Django

Tags: python, django, валидация

Здравствуйте!
Суть проблемы :
Нужно организовать валидацию на ввод даты в формате dd.mm.yyyy, желательно через 
regexvalidator или любым другим способом.
Тип поля не важен.
Форма сгенерирована в админке по нашей модели.
Ввод осуществляется там же.

Что пытаюсь сделать:

```
'(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{4})' - регулярка для валидации даты.
```

В редакторе работает, а тут нет.

```
# data regex validation
data_regex_tmp = re.compile(r'^(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{4})$',re.IGNORECASE)
data_regex = RegexValidator(regex=data_regex_tmp)
data_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[data_regex], null=True)
```

Валидацию телефона и email сделал через regexvalidator с датой не могу справиться. 
Подскажите где я не прав?

Буду рад работающему примеру.

Заранее спасибо !!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709386/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Поле DateField само выбросит исключение ValidationError, если в него придёт не дата.

Comment: А если тип поля IntegerField и нужно проверить ввод на соответсвие паттерну dd.mm.yyyy регуляркой ?
Прикол в том что регулярки я проверяю в редакторе и все нормально работает, а тут нет.
Не могу понять почему.

Comment: А как проявляется неработающий валидатор: ошибка, ошибочные данные валидны или наоборот?

Comment: Возможно, IntegerField не позволяет хранить числа с точками: An integer. Values from -2147483648 to 2147483647 are safe in all databases supported by Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField CharField выглядит более подходящим вариантом. Также есть специальное DateField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
Вопрос решился.